# Force PC to use HTTP instead HTTPS on pages like Facebook or Google

Tags: google-chrome, http, https, facebook

Is this possible? I know plugin for Firefox "HTTPS Everywhere", but i need opposite of it. 
Thank for answers.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why would you want to use an un-secure protocol?

Comment: We for example are developing a part of a web application for a customer. The application itself is consuming an API which is only HTTP. That's a serious problem for our environment configuration because we normally use HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible, because the host decides which requests it accepts. Google and Facebook are both HTTPS-only. Using HTTP will just get you a redirect to HTTPS.

Comment: Google is not HTTPS only, he is signed into Google+ (or chrome) which is why he is getting HTTPS.

Comment: @LDC3 Yes it is. Just try it yourself: Fire up your browser’s network monitor, and navigate to [http://www.google.com/search?q=test](http://www.google.com/search?q=test). You’ll get a redirect and nothing else via HTTP. /edit: And [here](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2296351/Goodbye-Keyword-Data-Google-Moves-Entirely-to-Secure-Search)’s an article on that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's non-sense.

It's common to see certain websites offering the same content through both protocols. This is you see the same content using `http://domain.com/page.html` and `https://domain.com/page.html`. But if HTTPS is configured it's usually for a reason. Eventually you will find some pages accessible only via HTTPS. Less common but possible too, you can find out part of their content is accessible via HTTP only. Finally, you could force your navigator to use HTTP only but most secure sites won't allow you to get all the content this way. If you happen to find a website exposing ALL its content using HTTP and HTTPS, the site has a configuration problem.

Comment: bullocks. Non-sense is only applicable to the misinterpretation of the recipient.
For example WebSockets will go over WSS if HTTPS is used. Internally used ESP8266 with MicroPython could require HTTP in such situations. 
Don't discard questions as non-sense if you can't find a decent application.